# Having trouble importing functions from another file in clojure

Tags: ubuntu, clojure

Not sure if it's something wrong with my namespaces, but I can't get my program to recognize and use the methods from my other clj file.

My code is as follows, I want to import the create_customer_index from db.clj and use it in menu.clj. The files are located in a folder called assign3, located in my home directory
[The file I need to use the method from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoyId.png)
[The menu.clj file, where I want to use the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwRfb.png)

But whenever I try to compile the code with said namespaces, I always get this error
[Error report in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbX0s.png)

I'm hoping a second pair of eyes can help me

I've tried looking at other questions/answers on this site, but they haven't been working out for me. Hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  It will also help, if
you provide a (cleaned up) file `tree` and what build tool you are
using.

Comment: And most likely not related to the problem: never use `def` inside `defn`. Use `let` instead.

Comment: Hi, it looks something related with how the program read the dependencies